# How to make hosts on a subnet unable to know about each other

Tags: networking, router, switch, vlan

I'm new to networking and have learned about VLANs, Subnetting, etc. What I'm searching for is a way to make all of the hosts on a subnet unable to communicate or even be aware of each other. The only host they should all be able to communicate with is the default route. What would this feature be called?

If I was implementing this from scratch I would put each host on it's own /30 subnet with a unique VLAN id. Obviously that is very cumbersome and I assume routers/switches have a feature to do this, I just can't seem to find the name of that feature.

I imagine businesses that have public wifi use whatever feature this is to isolate hosts from each other.

Ideally I could put all of the hosts using the forementioned isolation scheme on the same subnet so I can easily apply firewalling rules to all of them at once by configuring firewall rules for the subnet.

Comment: "What would this feature be called?" - It's called `Inter-VLAN routing` in order to accomplish it, there must be a route, to each VLAN defined by the router.  Is this an exam question?

Comment: It's not an exam question. I am just learning and I've been trying to isolate all my IoT devices at my house from each other using a Ubiquiti Router and Switch.

Comment: https://help.ui.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002359547-EdgeSwitch-Inter-VLAN-Routing

Comment: How does letting VLANs communicate solve my problem? I want the opposite, where all the hosts on a specific subnet cannot communicate with or have any way of being aware of each other.

Comment: Ok; I misunderstood the problem.  If you don't configure Inter-VLAN routing, individual VLANS, by default cannot communicate with one another

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Ethernet switches, this is sometimes called "private VLAN" or "port isolation", where only the designated "upstream" port (the router) can send/receive packets to all other ports in that VLAN.

It must be configured on the 'access' switches, right where the devices in question connect – it's not something that can be enforced just by the router alone.

For Wi-Fi the equivalent is "client isolation", configured on each access point.

In both cases, if you want some filtered access between hosts to remain (i.e. the equivalent of inter-VLAN routing through a firewall), the router needs to answer ARP on behalf of all hosts (sometimes called *local* proxy-ARP).